# Internet keeps getting Disconnected & Reconnected

Tags: networking

I have an Internet connection thru a Phone company which uses DSL modem to connect.

For past few weeks my net connection keeps getting disconnected for few seconds & it reconnects automatically.

I asked the service provider & they checked & even replaced some wires but of no help.

Funny thing is that sometimes there seems to be a rhythm where it disconnects for an average of 13 seconds or so plus or minus few seconds, for hours at a time.

I don't know how to attach an image to this post where it shows the pattern of connect & disconnect. I have taken an image using snagit to show the timing pattern. If someone can explain it, I can attach it here.

Thanks

Comment: Use [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to monitor your network traffic. It's possible you are being used as a [DDOS zombie](http://www.prolexic.com/knowledge-center-what-is-ddos-denial-of-service.html), or some other malware. If you see a storm of network traffic when your connectivity goes down, that could be the problem. I don't really have enough info from your question but to pull at strings, so it could be anything.

Comment: Would formatting windows partition & reinstalling the Win -7 that I use take care of Malware ? I do use Nod32 antivirus & Malwarebyte for malware. Never used Wireshark so just download & install it & is it easy to to check traffic with it ? I am not a techy.

Comment: Try booting some Linux live distribution and see whether you still get the same issue there.

Comment: Formatting and reinstalling Windows could take care of malware, but it's too soon to determine if malware has anything to do with it. For all I know it could be a flaky modem. Using a [Linux Live CD](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/try-ubuntu-before-you-install) is a good idea. If the problem doesn't show up when you're using Linux, then the problem has something to do with Windows. If not, it's your modem or ISP. Or something else.

Comment: Could it be NIC ? It is a Dell Workstation T-7500 & has built in NIC. It is under warranty so if I call Dell, they probably would replace the motherboard. So how would I or they know if it is NIC ? I know nothing about Linux, so how do I go about Linux live CD ? Where do I find it & how do I use it ? Do I need to uninstall Windows ? Would I have to learn a whole new OS Linux ? Thanks